# How to change event handler of a menu button?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, event-handling

I have a class that derives from `ContextMenuStrip`. This class has standard buttons and is used throughout the project:

```
public class ItemMenu : ContextMenuStrip
{
    public ItemMenu (IContainer container)
        : base(container)
    {
        MenuItemAdd = new ToolStripMenuItem("Add", null, AddNew);

        this.Items.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[] 
        { 
            mnuAdd, 
        });
    }

    public void AddNew(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Code to add new item here...
    }
}
```

And in the form:

```
cmsMenu = new ItemMenu(this.components);
```

Now I have a particular situation where I want that the form itself handles the code for adding an item.

How can I change the above class so that in default cases the class itself handles the actions, but in particular situations, other methods (events/delegates?) are used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following changes were required to get it to work:

```
public class ItemMenu : ContextMenuStrip
{
    public event EventHandler AddNewItem;

    public ItemMenu (IContainer container)
        : base(container)
    {
        MenuItemAdd = new ToolStripMenuItem("Add", null, AddNew);

        this.Items.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[] 
        { 
            mnuAdd, 
        });
    }

    public void AddNew(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler handler = AddNewItem;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(sender, e);
        }
        else
        {
            OnAddNew(sender, e);
        }
    }

    protected void OnAddNew(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Code to add new item here...
    }
}
```